# How would I change a loc to a sub IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

Title says it all, I just want to change this

```
addr:
loc_74E240
```

That's all.
This is for ROBLOX by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define `loc_XXXXXX` as a function you should use <kbd>P</kbd>. This is used to create a function where your cursor at. In some cases you'll need to undefine the current analysis done by IDA on a specific place and then redefine it as code. You can do it by pressing <kbd>U</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd>. Finally, by using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> you can edit an existing function.

Keep in mind that creating and editing functions might cause with unwanted [side-effects](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9005/ida-pro-side-effects-or-disadvantages-of-create-function), so be careful with that.

For more shortcuts, see the [Quick Reference Sheet](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/IDA_Pro_Shortcuts.pdf) by Hex-Rays.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `p` to define the address as a function. Be careful with that because you can ruin the disassembly.